# How to groupwise find the last common value between nested tibbles in R?

Tags: r, nested, tibble

Take this tibble:

```
df <- tibble(station = c("station1","station2","station2","station2"), 
         data = c(list(tibble(timestamp = c("2001-01-01","2002-01-02", "2002-01-03"), value=c(1,2,3))),
                  list(tibble(timestamp = NA, value = NA)), 
                  list(tibble(timestamp = c("2001-01-01","2002-01-02", "2002-01-03"), value=c(1,2,3))),
                  list(tibble(timestamp = c("2001-01-01","2002-01-02"), value=c(1,2)))))
```

I now want to group by the station. For each group i now want to find the last common timestamp in the related nested tibbles.

For station 1 this would be "2002-01-03"

For station 2 this would be "2002-01-02"

How can i get this result?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just to confirm, what does "last common timestamp" mean? The latest in time (2002-01-03 for both) or the last appearing (your answer)? Or last that appears in more than one grouping of observations, if more than one exists? (this would also produce your answer)

Comment: I want to find the last appearing timestamp that is present in all nested tibbles that belong to a group but ignore tibbles with NA. In the group "station2" that timestamp would be "2002-01-02".

Comment: Ignores tibbles with any NA or with only NA? So if a tibble has one NA but other data, throw out the whole tibble?

Comment: yes tibbles with NA should be ignored. All timestamps are in <date> format in the real dataset.

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>%  
  unnest(data) %>% 
  group_by(timestamp) %>%  
  filter(n_distinct(station) > 1) %>% # Get common timestamp across stations
  group_by(station) %>% 
  summarise(last_common = last(timestamp)) # Get the last common timestamp

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  station  last_date 
  <chr>    <chr>     
1 station1 2002-01-03
2 station2 2002-01-02
```

Comment: data <- tibble(
  station = c("Station1", "Station1", "Station1", "Station1", "Station1", "Station1", "Station1", "Station1", "Station1"),
  ts_id = c(65480010, 65480010, 65480010, 40025010, 40025010, 40025010, 3860010, 3860010, 3860010),
  timestamp = c("NA", "2023-01-20T07:15:00.000+01:00", "2023-01-20T07:30:00.000+01:00", "2023-01-20T07:15:00.000+01:00", "2023-01-20T07:30:00.000+01:00", "2023-01-20T07:45:00.000+01:00", "2023-01-20T07:15:00.000+01:00", "2023-01-20T07:30:00.000+01:00", "2023-01-20T07:45:00.000+01:00"),
  values = c(NA, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 37, 37))

Comment: Your code works for my given example. It seems that the example i provided did not fully catch the problem.
Your code failes to deliver the right answer for the data above. The latest common timestamp for station1 across the ts_ids should be 2023-01-20T06:30 becaus thats the latest timestamp, that appears in all ts_ids in the station1 group. I cant get my head around whats going wrong. Is there a solution?

Comment: Please keep in mind, that this is only part of the whole dataset. There are alot of stations, that can have one or more timeseries. Some of the timeseries can have only NA values and they are not necessarily the same length.
 The task is to get the latest timestamp that appear in all ts_id that belong to a station. You can transform the timestamp to <ddtm> format with lubridate if you want to. The tibble above is already unnested.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Solution to the second example:
`data %>%
  group_by(station, timestamp) %>% 
  mutate(shared = n_distinct(ts_id)) %>% 
  group_by(station) %>% 
  filter(shared == max(shared)) %>% 
  summarise(last_common = max(timestamp))`